# Build fails when building Azure function with MSBuild version 15 from command line

Tags: azure, msbuild, azure-functions

I have created an Azure function application in Visual Studio 2017 (as detailed [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/05/10/azure-function-tools-for-visual-studio-2017/)) and the application builds without an issue from within Visual Studio. However when I try and build the application from the command line (simply running `msbuild.exe mysolution.sln`) with MSBuild version 15, I get errors such as:

`error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Azure' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)` which is most likely because the application references Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs by default as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#package-management).

So I presume I need to restore the Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs package somehow but I am unsure on how to restore packages in an Azure function application manually. I created a `project.json` file and listed the package in there but that didn't work. I then created a `packages.json` nuget file and that didn't work either. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried simply doing a `nuget restore`, just like with any other msbuild based project?

Comment: I just tried this using `nuget restore mysolution.sln` and get the message `Nothing to do. None of the projects in this solution specify any packages for NuGet to restore.` If I knew how Visual Studio was restoring the packages, I could just copy that.

Comment: I just tried on my test app (https://github.com/davidebbo-test/FunctionAppVS2017_3Preview), and `nuget restore` followed by `msbuild` works great. Make sure you do this from a dev prompt for VS 2017 **preview**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked this out - I need to run `msbuild.exe mysolution.sln /t:restore` first before I run `msbuild.exe mysolution.sln` which I found from the information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/msbuild-targets).